# How to create lines crossing through cursor position in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cursor, lines

I would like to find a way to create two perpendicular lines, crossing at the cursor position and spanning across the entire canvas. Since I'll be presenting some complex and rather chaotic fully-meshed diagrams to the user, I want to give them a way to quickly find the cursor.
What is the best way to achieve this in JavaScript? 
My Problem is: I'm still new to JavaScript and the endless libraries that are available for this kind of stuff so I really have no clue what's best to use. I found a similar question for QT GraphicsView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698029/best-way-to-create-a-long-line-or-cross-line-cursor-in-qt-graphicsview) and was wondering whether there might be a library or script out there that can achieve the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This isn't a "we do it for you" kind of site. What have you *tried* already.

Comment: Edited my question, sorry. Of course I'm aware this isn't a "do this for me" site - nobody would learn anything from that. However, I must admit I suck at knowing "what to use" for what I want to build, and so if somebody could just point me in the right direction, I'd already be happy.